# Spark web UI for an application becomes empty after it finishes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am using Spark 1.5.2 running on Yarn.

Sometimes, the Spark web UI for an application becomes empty after it finishes, ***why ? How can I resolve it ?***

For example, today I launched a pyspark app, and followed it's progress on the console and the Spark Web UI. So I know that it ran correctly as you can see on the screeshot below :

- [The DAG visualizer, when processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2oWB.jpg)

But after the process, the history becomes empty :

- [The Spark Job History shows an empty history when the application finished the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLn16.jpg)

When the script finished, I got the following warning on the console (I don't know if it is linked to the issue):

> 16/05/02 17:36:49 WARN AkkaRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = RemoveExecutor(2,Yarn deallocated the executor 2 (container container_1460361870585_2312_01_000004))] in 1 attempts
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler#313705968]] had already been terminated.. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
>   [...]
>   16/05/02 17:36:51 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [...] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
>   16/05/02 17:36:51 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [...] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]

Comment: I don't know why does it actually happen however you always can save event_log and then visualize it (like it was during computation) using history-server.

Answer (score 0):

From the second screenshot, it was the `Jobs` page. You need to click the job id link in order to see a job DAG.

Comment: I know, but the DAG is empty too, I just took 2 different pages.

Comment: I see. Did you call `SparkContext.stop` at the end of your application? If not, it may not be able to write the events when the application is killed forcely.